# @Transactional for any Exceptions in Spring

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I am looking using `@Transactional` on one of the Service methods. However when an exception occurs, the transaction is not getting rolled back. I tried the same with `@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)`. My code as follows:-

```
    @Override
    @Transactional(rollbackFor=Throwable.class)
    public boolean addUser(User user) throws Exception{
        boolean userAdded = userDao.addUser(user);                  
        boolean userRegistrationRecorded = userDao.recordUserRegistraionDetails(user);      
        return true;
    }
```

I read lot of posts and every one says that Spring handles only `RuntimeException`s and not checked `Exception`s other than `RmiException`. I need a solution that works for any kind of `Exception`. Some one suggested me to write own annotation, where as others suggested of having a `TransactionManager` as part of `applicationContext.xml` file. A detailed solution will definitely help me.

By the way I am using Spring `JdbcTemplate`. The strange thing I observe is though the `Exception`s raised by Spring are `RuntimeException`s the transaction is not getting rolled back. I am trying to raise an `Exception` by adding the same `User` in the above scenario.

My applicationContext.xml is as follows:-

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.chaperone.services.security.*" />

    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
        <property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="${DATABASE_URL}" />
        <property name="username" value="${DATABASE_USER_NAME}" />
        <property name="password" value="${DATABASE_PASSWORD}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: edit your question to add new information

Comment: share your application-context and servlet context files

Comment: `@Transactional` without `<tx:annotation-driven />` and a correctly defined `PlatformTransactionManager` is going to do nothing. An annotation is just metadata if you don't specify anything to work with the annotation it is pretty much useless. Regarding the rollback please clarify which database you are using as there are databases (or table types) that don't even support transactions.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I am using MySql DB. I have <bean id="dataSource"
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
  <property name="url" value="${DATABASE_URL}" />
  <property name="username" value="${DATABASE_USER_NAME}" />
  <property name="password" value="${DATABASE_PASSWORD}" />
 </bean> as part of my applicationContext.xml

Comment: @RafikBELDI, Please see the application-context in my edited post.

Comment: as @M.Deinum said , add `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"
   />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ease-of-use afforded by the use of the `@Transactional` annotation is best illustrated in  this [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations)

you have to add :

`<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />`